# I have a problem when installing Ubuntu (I cannot select installation type)

Tags: system-installation

When I try to install Ubuntu from a Live session, I do not see any options on the "Installation type" page:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Even when Gparted is closed i get this same interface

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of computer you are trying to install Ubuntu onto? Could you also include some additional details, like whether the computer will *only* have Ubuntu, or whether it will have other operating systems to boot into as well? This may help someone offer a solution 

Comment: Did you change UEFI setting for drives to AHCI from RAID or Intel RST, and if dual booting you must add AHCI driver into Windows first. Is Windows fast start up off?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have GParted running. GParted makes all the drives inaccessible.

Close both GParted and the installer, and run the installer again.

Comment: GParted only shows the cdrom filesystem, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I see. But are CDROMS formatted as fat32? I don't have a CD with me to check.

Comment: Should be ISO9660, I think.

Comment: It might be a wrongly mounted (no idea why) HDD/SSD.